# Делегировать нажатие одной кнопки другой

Tags: javafx

У меня есть Button в javafx приложении, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на нее нажималась другая(ColorPicker). Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: У ColorPicker уже реализован функционал при нажатии(всплывает меню выбора цвета) мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии другой, самой обычной кнопки Button, вызывался этот же функционал.

Comment: А picker.show(); не помогает?

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо, этот метод я и искал